# Show or insert a SQL result in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have the next code

```
select
  MULTIMEDIA_COMPONENTES_HMI.COSTO * :P4_CANTIDAD,
  MULTIMEDIA_COMPONENTES_HMI.COSTO * :P4_CANTIDAD as COSTO
from MULTIMEDIA_COMPONENTES_HMI 
where num=:P4_COSTO;
```

I want to show in a textbox the result or directly insert the result in the database when the create button is press. How can I do this or what type of element should I use to show the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more than one Solution for this question. If you want to load the values to the textbox as the Query is executet, and display the result immediately for the user, you have to use a Dynamic Action, triggered by a Button or a value Change Event on the Items you referred to: P4_CANTIDAD or P4_COSTO.
This Dynamic Action could have a TRUE Trigger with a execute PL/SQL Code Action.

The PL/SQL Query could do Something like display all the changed data, and insert the new information in the database.

```
select
  MULTIMEDIA_COMPONENTES_HMI.COSTO * :P4_CANTIDAD into :P4_TEXTBOX
from MULTIMEDIA_COMPONENTES_HMI 
where num=:P4_COSTO;

Insert into MULTIMEDIA_COMPONENTES_HMI 
(COSTO)
values
(:P4_COSTO);
```

When you create a Dynamic Action, you have to enter the Items to Submit and Items to Return below the PL/SQL Code Textarea, to set the correct Session State without submitting the complete page.

Another solution without the Dynamic Action would be to simply create a Page process after Submit and Insert your Data to The Database. Then create a Page Process After Header an refil your Items with the new values from the Database, or defining the Select Into statement in the Source Region of your Item.

Comment: The query works, but at the moment that I want to show the result in the Text Field :P4_TEXTBOX don't show the result

Comment: maybe you have to create a on Set Value Dynamic Action as well at the exact time you want to change your :P4_TEXTBOX Value. Directly after executing the Query above.